# using JBoss7 with pacemaker

Tags: jboss, high-availability, pacemaker

Recently I'm trying to implement HA(High Available) on several redHat servers.
Tools:
     pacemaker, JBoss
I only found this resource agent(http://linux-ha.org/doc/man-pages/re-ra-jboss.html) which only support JBoss5 and Jboss6. But my JBoss server is JBoss6 EAP which is actually JBoss7 so that I failed to implement HA using JBoss7 and pacemaker.

I have two questions:
1. I googled the resource agent script to find appropriate script to support JBoss7 but I failed. Is there anywhere I can find such a script?
2. If nobody has offered such script, how could I write such a script? Any documents which can offer any help?

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why Pacemake + JBoss 7 for HA? JBoss provide HA configuration. See: http://blog.akquinet.de/2012/07/19/scalable-ha-clustering-with-jboss-as-7-eap-6/ and https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/High+Availability+Guide

Comment: session-replication needs all servers to run jboss so that when one server stops, other server can response. But I hope that at any time, there is only one server is running and when it stops, other servers will start automatically to response.

Comment: You don't need enable session replication, you can create a cluster with standalone instances where you do load balancing and failover (for example with mod_cluster).

Comment: thanks for your reply. But the point is that at any time, I hope that there is only one server running the jboss and other servers will start automatically only when the running jboss crashes. And in my opinion, load balance or failover require all servers to run jboss at the same time and when one server crashed, other servers will response to the users. Actually, I think these two solutions are different.

Comment: Try with [LSB resource agent](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/LSB_Resource_Agents)